# Convert FreeType GlyphSlot Bitmap To Vulkan BGRA

Tags: c++, data-conversion, vulkan, freetype2

I'm trying to convert a FreeType GlyphSlot Bitmap to Vulkan BGRA format.

```
void DrawText(const std::string &text) {
    //  WIDTH & HEIGHT == dst image dimensions
    FT_GlyphSlot Slot = face->glyph;
    buffer.resize(WIDTH*HEIGHT*4);

    int dst_Pitch = WIDTH * 4;

    for (auto c : text) {
        FT_Error error = FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER);
        if (error) {
            printf("FreeType: Load Char Error\n");
            continue;
        }

        auto char_width = Slot->bitmap.width;
        auto char_height = Slot->bitmap.rows;

        uint8_t* src = Slot->bitmap.buffer;
        uint8_t* startOfLine = src;

        for (int y = 0; y < char_height; ++y) {
            src = startOfLine;
            for (int x = 0; x < char_width; ++x) {

                //  y * dst_Pitch   == Destination Image Row
                //  x * 4           == Destination Image Column
                int dst = (y*dst_Pitch) + (x*4);

                //  Break if we have no more space to draw on our
                //  destination texture.
                if (dst + 4 > buffer.size()) { break; }

                auto value = *src;
                src++;

                buffer[dst]     = 0xff;     // +0 == B
                buffer[dst+1]   = 0xff;     // +1 == G
                buffer[dst+2]   = 0xff;     // +2 == R
                buffer[dst+3]   = value;    // +3 == A
            }
            startOfLine += Slot->bitmap.pitch;
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving me garbled output. I'm not sure what I need to do to properly convert to Vulkan `B8G8R8A8`. I feel like moving from left to right in the buffer we write to our Vulkan texture is incorrect and maybe Vulkan is expecting I add the pixels into the buffer in a different way?

I understand this code will write each letter on top of one another, I will implement taking advantage of `Slot->advance` after I can properly draw at least a single letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact that I had `VkImageCreateInfo` `tiling` set to `VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL`. After changing it to `VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` I received the correct output.

Taken straight from https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkImageTiling.html

> VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL specifies optimal tiling (texels are laid out
>   in an implementation-dependent arrangement, for more optimal memory
>   access).
>
> VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR specifies linear tiling (**texels are laid out in
>   memory in row-major order**, possibly with some padding on each row).

While I may not be rendering garbage now, my letters are still backwards and seemingly drawing from right to left instead of left to right.
[image]
You can see the green 'the' in the top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you resize `buffer` with every character (which will leave the previous data at the start of the newly allocated space) but when storing the data for the new character `c` you overwrite the start of the buffer since `dst` is 0.  You probably want to set `dst` the `buffer.size()` from before the `resize` call.

```
int dst = /*previous buffer size*/;
```

Comment: I didn't notice that, thank you. I'm still receiving garbled output on the final texture. I believe this is because my application is expecting B8G8R8A8 formatted data or the data I'm filling into the buffer is just garbage.